# How to read JSON data type in mysql using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

Mysql 5.7 introduced the JSON data type which offers tonnes of query functions.

Since there isn't a compatible resultset function, how and what to i do use retrieve the data stored in this datatype.

Comment: Have you tried reading it as `String`? Then you could use some library like Jackson to parse this string into a POJO.

Comment: no i haven't actually tried reading it. I couldn't find a matching function so i got confused. I have now saved it as LONGTEXT in mysql. that definitely converts to string

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html .... seems like it can't be done as of this moment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `rs.getString`, because `getString` used with `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, we can consider `JSon` like a `String` type, so you can get the result, using `getString`.

---

**Simple Example**

Double check with MySQL 5.7 and PostgreSQL 9.4 :

**MySQL 5.7 SQL**

```
create database db_test;
create table table_test(json JSON);
INSERT INTO table_test VALUES('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}');
```

**CODE**

```
public static void checkJSon() {
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_username, DB_password);
        String q = "SELECT * FROM table_test";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(q);
        preparedStatement.execute();
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("json"));
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It print to me :

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

Comment: i am not saving JSON as a string inside varchar or text. I was talking about the new JSON data type  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html  according to mysql docs, the connector does not support this type yet

Comment: i know @Kushan for example you are using `CREATE TABLE t1 (jdoc JSON);` `JSON` in your database, so to get this result you have to use `getString` to get JSon

Comment: have you tested if this works? if so i'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Kushan yes double check with MySQL 5.7 and PostgreSQL 9.4 work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking, I was trying it with Mysql 5.7, but the methods suggested above don't handle non-ascii data quite well a lot of asian characters etc). They end up displaying as garbled.

The solution is to read the raw bytes using getBinaryStream. The code is demonstrated below:

```
public String fromJSON(ResultSet rs, String fieldName){
    InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(fieldName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String content = br.lines().reduce("", String::concat);
    br.close();
    return content;
}
```

The above could be encapsulated in a function fromJSON and used widely.
e.g

```
PreparedStatement st = getStatement("select json from x;");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    return fromJSON(rs, "json");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case JDBC isn't a hard requirement, recent [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) versions implemented an out-of-the-box way to map SQL JSON values to arbitrary Java types using the popular JSON mapping libraries [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) (whichever can be found on your classpath). You can then write:

```java
List<MyClass> list =
ctx.select(TABLE.ID, TABLE.JSON_COLUMN)
   .from(TABLE)
   .where(...)
   .fetchInto(MyClass.class);
```

With, for example:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public int id;
    public MyOtherClass jsonColumn;
}

public class MyOtherClass {
    public String something;
    public List<String> list;
}
```

Assuming your `JSON_COLUMN` contains data of the form:

```json
{
  "something": "x",
  "list": [ "a", "b", "c" ]
}
```

This also works with all the natively supported SQL/JSON functions, [to create such JSON documents on the fly](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/10/09/nesting-collections-with-jooq-3-14s-sql-xml-or-sql-json-support/).

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)